# Overlaying ggplot data layers

Tags: r, date, dataframe, ggplot2, time-series

I am trying to overlay two different length datasets within ggplot.

**Dataset 1**: dataframe `r` where `m` is the date and `V2` is the value with a range between -1 to +1:

```
> r
             m         V2
19991221    1
19910703    -0.396825397
19850326    0.916666667
19890328    -0.473053892
19610912    -0.75
20021106    -0.991525424
19940324    -1
19840522    -0.502145923
19780718    1
19811222    -0.447154472
19781017    0
19761108    -0.971014493
19791006    1
19891219    0.818181818
19851217    0.970149254
19980818    0.808219178
19940816    -0.985185185
19790814    -0.966666667
19990203    -0.882352941
19831220    1
19830114    -1
19980204    -0.991489362
19941115    -0.966101695
19860520    -0.986206897
19761019    -0.666666667
19900207    -0.983870968
19731010    0
19821221    -0.833333333
19770517    1
19800205    0.662337662
19760329    -0.545454545
19810224    -0.957446809
20000628    -0.989473684
19911105    -0.988571429
19960924    -0.483870968
19880816    1
19860923    1
20030506    -1
20031209    -1
19950201    -0.974025974
19790206    1
19811117    -0.989304813
19950822    -1
19860212    0.808219178
19730821    -0.463203463
19991221    1
19910703    -0.396825397
19850326    0.916666667
19890328    -0.473053892
19610912    -0.75
20021106    -0.991525424
19940324    -1
19840522    -0.502145923
19780718    1
19811222    -0.447154472
19781017    0
19761108    -0.971014493
19791006    1
19891219    0.818181818
19851217    0.970149254
19980818    0.808219178
19940816    -0.985185185
19790814    -0.966666667
19990203    -0.882352941
19831220    1
19830114    -1
19980204    -0.991489362
19941115    -0.966101695
19860520    -0.986206897
19761019    -0.666666667
19900207    -0.983870968
19731010    0
19821221    -0.833333333
19770517    1
19800205    0.662337662
19760329    -0.545454545
19810224    -0.957446809
20000628    -0.989473684
19911105    -0.988571429
19960924    -0.483870968
19880816    1
19860923    1
20030506    -1
20031209    -1
19950201    -0.974025974
19790206    1
19811117    -0.989304813
19950822    -1
19860212    0.808219178
19730821    -0.463203463
19991221    1
19910703    -0.396825397
19850326    0.916666667
19890328    -0.473053892
19610912    -0.75
20021106    -0.991525424
19940324    -1
19840522    -0.502145923
19780718    1
19811222    -0.447154472
19781017    0
19761108    -0.971014493
19791006    1
19891219    0.818181818
19851217    0.970149254
19980818    0.808219178
19940816    -0.985185185
19790814    -0.966666667
19990203    -0.882352941
19831220    1
19830114    -1
19980204    -0.991489362
19941115    -0.966101695
19860520    -0.986206897
19761019    -0.666666667
19900207    -0.983870968
19731010    0
19821221    -0.833333333
19770517    1
19800205    0.662337662
19760329    -0.545454545
19810224    -0.957446809
20000628    -0.989473684
19911105    -0.988571429
19960924    -0.483870968
19880816    1
19860923    1
20030506    -1
20031209    -1
19950201    -0.974025974
19790206    1
19811117    -0.989304813
19950822    -1
19860212    0.808219178
19730821    -0.463203463
```

use these lines to generate r

```
m<-gsub("-", "/", as.Date(as.character(fileloc$V1), "%Y%m%d"))
r<-cbind(m, fileloc[2])
colnames(r)
r
```

**Dataset 2:** The following data sets which defines the recession period in US:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("USREC",src="FRED")
getSymbols("UNRATE", src="FRED")
unrate.df <- data.frame(date= index(UNRATE),UNRATE$UNRATE)

start <- index(USREC[which(diff(USREC$USREC)==1)])
end   <- index(USREC[which(diff(USREC$USREC)==-1)-1])

reccesion.df <- data.frame(start=start, end=end[-1])
recession.df <- subset(reccesion.df, start >= min(unrate.df$date))
```

The resulting `recession.df`

```
> recession.df
        start        end
1 1948-12-01 1949-10-01
2 1953-08-01 1954-05-01
3 1957-09-01 1958-04-01
.....
11 2008-01-01 2009-06-01
```

**Plotting**:

I can generate separate scatter plots with the following:

```
ggplot(r, aes(V2, r$m,  colour=V2))+
 geom_point()+xlab(label='Tone Score')+ylab(label='Dates')
```

and timeseries with shaded region for recession with:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=unrate.df, aes(x=date, y=UNRATE)) +
  geom_rect(data=recession.df,
            aes(xmin=start,xmax=end, ymin=0,ymax=max(unrate.df$UNRATE)), 
            fill="red", alpha=0.2)
```

How do I merge these plots to see overlay those scatter plot over the time series?

Comment: Hey :) questions like this generally benefit from including all the data required, or by producing a sample dataset as demonstrated within my answer.

Comment: Hi Mikey, just added the entire dataset for ref. Also added couple of lines of R script to format data. thank you

Comment: Does my answer work with your dataset? It looks like it should but I haven't rerun it.

Comment: looks like its working, I have all points clustered at . I think its more related to of not having the date sequence.

Comment: Great that it works. Can you mark it as accepted and upvote please :)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without you providing the full dataset for the question, I have generated some random data for the dates between the dates `1973/08/21` and `1999/12/21`:

```
set.seed(123)
r <- data.frame(m = seq.Date(as.Date("2017/12/21"), as.Date("1950/08/21"), 
                         length.out = 135),
            V2 = rnorm(n = 135, mean = 0, sd = 0.5))
```

You can overlay multiple layers within a ggplot by adding different a different `data` and `aes` arguments for each of the `geom_` items you are calling.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = r, aes(x = m, y = V2, colour=V2))+
  geom_line(data=unrate.df, aes(x=date, y=UNRATE)) +
  geom_rect(data=recession.df,
            aes(xmin=start, xmax=end, ymin=0, ymax=max(unrate.df$UNRATE)), 
            fill="red", alpha=0.2) +
  xlab(label='Tone Score')+ylab(label='Dates')
```

[image]